# Autocomplete for upper-case constants with underscores in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, camelcasing

is there a possibility to activate autocomplete for constants with underscores `_`?

I have a class with many constants, where many of them begin same. Example:

```
// Component details
public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_MATERIAL_NUMBER = "name";
public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_OVERALL_WORK_STATUS = "componentOverallWorkStatus";
public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_RELEASE_STATUS = "freigabestatus";
public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_DESCRIPTION = "label";
public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_AMOUNT = "newAmount";
public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_BASE_QUANTITY_UNIT = "basismengeneinheit";
public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_PRODUCER = "hersteller";
public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_PRODUCER_FRAGMENT_NUMBER = "herstellerteilenummer";
public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_EXCLUDE_ALTERNATIVE_ARTICLE = "componentExcludeAlternativeArticle";
public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_GENERAL_INFO = "componentGeneralInfo";
```

They all start with `PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT` and if I now begin to type this

```
System.out.println(ClassWithThoseConstants.P
```

and press `Ctrl + Space`. Now I got all constansts starting with `P`, which is fine. But now I'd like to go further with camelcase style, i.e. `PNCP` which shall lead to the options:

`PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_PRODUCER` and `PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_PRODUCER_FRAGMENT_NUMBER`.

Typing `P_N_C_P` doesn't help either. Is there a possibility? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Good question. I would have tried the `PNC..` route too. Worst case, you could define a template that inserts `public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_COMPONENT_{$cursor}`. Side note: in a programming context, camel-case more traditional refers to lower-case first letter. "Title case" might be a less ambiguous choice.

Comment: `enum PropertyNameComponent { MATERIAL_NUMBER("name"), OVERALL_WORKSTATUS("componentOverallWorkStatus"), ...; }`

Comment: @Joop Some might wanna try refactoring this by using enums for kind of grouping, but I asked this question in a more general intention. I simply want to search through my constants like I do when searching for a class using `Ctrl+Shift+T` or similar, with camelcase.

Comment: Try setting this in your shortcuts in the Preferences Menu

Comment: Could you be a little more precise please and give me an example of what you mean? How can I create something like this as a generic shortcut..?